# Is it possible to compile Java11 code to Java8 bytecode and run on 8?

Tags: java, maven

I'm playing with some dependencies and compilation to older releases using java 11. I migrated one dependency to Java 11 and works fine, but we still have to run it Tomcat 7 or 8 on Java8. Is it possible to use the `--release` flag to compile code which uses `var`, `stream().dropwhile(...)` or `Map.of(...)` and run on 8?

Release flag suggest that it should be possible:

> --release release Compiles against the public, supported and documented API for a specific VM version. Supported release targets
>   are 6, 7, 8, and 9.

This project is a dependency, stand-alone works fine with SprinBoot2.1 and Java11, but needs to be run in Java8.

My maven plugin compiler settings:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.8.0</version>
    <configuration>
        <release>8</release>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

but this forbids compiling >jdk8 specific code. I'm using latest maven 3.6.0 and mvn compiler as above.

Attempt to compile:

```
return List.of("dsadas", "dasdadddds", "£dsada", "dasdas")
        .stream()
        .dropWhile(s -> s.contains("das"))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

throws error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.0:compile (default-compile) on project api: Compilation failure: Compilation failure: 
[ERROR] /home/agilob/Projects/.....java:[58,13] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class var
[ERROR]   location: 
[ERROR] /home/agilob/Projects/....java:[43,20] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   method of(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String)
[ERROR]   location: interface java.util.List
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
```

Comment: Part of the problem seems to be that the static factory [`List.of`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/List.html#of-E...-) was added in Java 9, and is therefore not present in 8’s runtime library.

Comment: Also the method dropWhile of java.base.Stream was added in Java 9 so it is not part of the supported API. See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html

Comment: Yes, and var was added in Java10, but as these are compile time cosmetic changes to the language, couldn't they be statically linked and bundled in the .class and .jar?

Comment: @agilob in theory, yes. In practice I don't know of any tool which tries to do this. If you find one, let me know.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It is not possible. Only the API methods and classes of the targeted Java platform are allowed.

That is defined in [JEP 247: Compile for Older Platform Versions](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/247)

> A new command-line option, --release, is defined, which automatically
> configures the compiler to produce class files that will link against
> an implementation of the given platform version.

The relevant part that says what can be used is:

> For N < 9, the documented APIs consist of the public APIs that were on javac's default bootclasspath for JDK N.
>
> For N >= 9, the documented APIs consist of (i) the APIs exported from those modules in the JDK image which are part of the documentation of JDK N; and (ii) the API exported from the jdk.unsupported module (documented in JEP 260).

Answer (score 5):

It is possible now with https://github.com/bsideup/jabel

> Jabel - javac 12 plugin that makes it emit Java 8 bytecode

Comment: It is not possible, because `dropWhile()` and `Map.of()` methods don't exist in the Java 8 Runtime Library. Jabel will allow use of `var`, but that doesn't answer this question.

Answer (score -2):

For idea use

[image]

It`s works for me

Comment: That's not what question is about